# GWT 2.6.1 refusing to launch dev mode in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I was running a project with GWT 2.7.0, but decided to downgrade to 2.6.1 to be more compliant with the rest of the dev team.

However, now I get:

```
Unknown argument: -nosuperDevMode
Google Web Toolkit 2.6.1
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.6, 1.7]] module[s]
```

when I try to run the application.

I specified to use GWT 2.6.1 as the default for all projects. This project uses the defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to edit you launch configuration.
The parameter only exists in GWT 2.7. If you created the launch-config with GWT 2.7 it may still be present after the downgrade in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Goto debug configuration and in Arguments tab remove -nosuperDevMode